# Android JUnit Test Framework

Tags: android, android-activity, junit, android-testing

I am observing an unusual behavior in my Android JUnit Test Case. The test case is for testing Activity state management of a simple Calculator Application. Here is what my test case suppose to do.

1. Launch Activity ( Done in setup )
2. Get reference to UI Elelments ( done in setup )
3. Press buttons to write something on TextView
4. Change orientation of Activity so it is recreated and TextView's text is cleared out
5. Verify that textview is clean

While i see on emulator that at step 5, the activity's TextView shows empty Text Field but in Junit test code when i do TextView.getText(), it returns the old value which was entered before changing orientation.

Here is my Test Case code. The last assertion should fail as Activity is recreated and I am not managing Activity state by onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState()

```
    public void testOrientationState(){

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            keypad.get(com.example.simplecalculator.R.id.button7).performClick();
            keypad.get(com.example.simplecalculator.R.id.button9).performClick();
        }
    });
    CharSequence beforeOrientationChange = display.getText();
    assertEquals(beforeOrientationChange,"79");
    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    CharSequence afterOrientationChange= (CharSequence) ((TextView)mActivity.findViewById(com.example.simplecalculator.R.id.textView)).getText();
    assertEquals(beforeOrientationChange,afterOrientationChange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android may terminate an `Activity` and restart it after an orientation change. So you should not rely on the existing `Activity` reference if you want to check for the state after the orientation change.